# Inverse function theorem and finding the open set that allows $f$ to have a local inverse

Tags: inverse-function-theorem

The inverse function theorem says that there exists an open set $U$ such that there is a local inverse of $f$ around a point $a$.
However, how would we actually find an open set containing this point $a$?
In particular, the function
$$f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} x^2 y + 2y - x \\ 3xy + 4x \end{pmatrix}$$ with the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so, the inverse function theorem holds when the determinant of the jacobian of $f$ is non-zero right? And it is in this case

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but doesn't this case satisfy both requirements?  
The jacobian (differential) is non-zero (so has maximum rank) and also the function in question takes in two variables (a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$) and it also gives out a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: ups, my bad. Sorry